# What is the "__proto__" in the chrome dev tools for and more importantly is there a way to suppress it as an option?

Tags: google-chrome-devtools

I keep seeing **proto** at the dev tools for a long time. When I dig into it, I can never get something useful anyway.

It could be useful for others, but I prefer to not see it at all. 
I'm curious to see what is it for and if there is a way to turn off the additional info that comes with it so an output like the following can be lightened up?

```
author:"haluk"
dateCreated:"2017-12-09 17:39:56"
description:null
image:null
language:["Chinese *"]
learnerType:Array(1)
0:"Traditional"
length:1
__proto__
:
Array(0)
recID:"388"
status:"draft"
title:"mujgan"
topic:Array(1)
0:""
length:1
__proto__
:
Array(0)
__proto__
:
Object
...
```

At least, for me, it would be so much better to look at something like this:

```
author:"haluk"
dateCreated:"2017-12-09 17:39:56"
description:null
image:null
language:["Chinese *"]
learnerType:Array(1)
0:"Traditional"
recID:"388"
status:"draft"
title:"mujgan"
topic:Array(1)
0:""
```

Is there a way to tell Chrome to not to get into the **proto**?

Comment: I don't think there is an easy way without extension, but you can try `JSON.stringify(yourObject, 0, 2)`

Comment: That's a nice work around! but I get this error:       `console.log ( JSON.stringify(this.learningPlan, 0, 2)); // ERROR in ... Argument of type '0' is not assignable to parameter of type '(string | number)[]'.webpack: Failed to compile.`

Comment: `JSON.stringify(yourObject, null, 2)` (2 can be the number of spaces or a string to use as indentation). The second parameter is supposed to be a function or array, and the third parameter to be string or number https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify

Comment: thanks. that does it.